# JSP include directive, jsp:include action, relative vs. absolute paths

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, path, jspinclude

I am doing some basic templating in my JSP-based webapp.  For example, I want to have a standard header and footer (basic HTML) that I pull into each of my JSPs.

My content JSP is at `/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp`, and I have template JSPs at `/WEB-INF/jsp/template/`, such as `/WEB-INF/jsp/template/Body-Footer.jsp`.

So now, within `home.jsp`, I want to pull in my template files.  First, I try the `jsp:include` action:

```
<jsp:include page="template/Body-Footer.jsp"></jsp:include>
```

It generates the error `javax.servlet.ServletException: File &quot;/template/Body-Footer.jsp&quot; not found`

Strange to me, considering that Eclipse says that the path is valid.

Okay, so then I switch to the include directive:

```
<%@ include file="template/Body-Footer.jsp" %>
```

This works just fine, pulls in my footer HTML.

But why does the `jsp:include` not work?  After some experimentation, I find that putting in the absolute path does get it to work:

```
<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/jsp/template/Body-Footer.jsp"></jsp:include>
```

Now it works fine, no errors.

So here's my question: why?  Why do I (apparently) need to use an absolute path with the `jsp:include` action, but not with the include directive?

Comment: You might want to start [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879906/what-is-the-difference-between-jspinclude-page-and-include-file).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/WEB-INF/jsp/template/Body-Footer.jsp` is not an absolute path.  Its also a relative path.  The problem is that `template/Body-Footer.jsp` is an incomplete relative path, whereas the other is complete.  That is, the paths are relative to your app path.  Since `/WEB-INF/` is under your app path, you have to include it.   Absolute path means like `C:/program files/tomcat/webapps/yourapp/WEB-INF/jsp/template/Body-Footer.jsp`

Comment: The other path is absolute regarding the application context URL.

Comment: Its absolute RELATIVE to the application context, thus not really absolute at all. There's a clear confusion in terminology going on.  Of course your relative paths have to be complete, otherwise, how would they work?

Comment: That's what I've said. I don't negate the fact that they are relatives paths after all.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to WHY - The `jsp:include` is a runtime directive unlike the `<%@ include ... %>` directive which happens to be a compile time directive (translation time, actually).

See more on: [JSP Performance using jsp:include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479218/jsp-performance-using-jspinclude)

Bottom line - directives are run against different folders as a base.

Btw. JSP pages should be outside of WEB-INF folder, if you want to follow official recommendation:

[The Java EE 6 Tutorial - Web Module Structure](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnadx.html)

Comment: This is helpful, thanks.  However, on your recommendation of putting the JSPs outside of the WEB-INF folder, maybe I missed it but I couldn't see something in that link that recommended that.  In support of putting the JSPs in WEB-INF, we have this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825907/why-put-jsp-in-web-inf

Comment: Placing your JSP files under `/WEB-INF/` is a common practice which "hides" the pages from direct-requests, allowing you to ensure that all requests are directed e.g. through a controller or other mechanism that protects your scripts from casual browsing.

Answer (score 0):

I read JSP 2.0 spec and here:

```
 Relative URL Specifications

 * A context-relative path is a path that starts with a slash (/).
 It is to be interpreted as relative to the application to which
 the JSP page or tag file belongs. That is, its ServletContext
 object provides the base context URL.

 * A page relative path is a path that does not start with a
 slash (/). It is to be in- terpreted as relative to the current
 JSP page, or the current JSP file or tag file, depending on where
 the path is being used.
```

For now `javax.servlet.ServletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/test/test.jsp")` is null for security reason.

Assume that *context-relative path* is path from your WAR root.